# Mockito fails to mock Rest API call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Using Mockito to test a REST API, always get an error. I'm trying to mock the

> apiClient.execute(buildApiCall("POST", url, reqBody), localVarReturnType);

But nothing has worked, any help here would be greatly appreciated

system under test

```
public CreateUser createUser(String fullname, String username, String password, String departmentName) {
    String url = "/api/v1/account/?apikey=" + apiKey;
    String randomUsername = generateRandomString(20);
    CreateUser payload = new CreateUser();
    payload.setFullName(fullname);
    payload.setUsername(username);
    payload.setPassword(generatePassword((password != null) ? password : generatePassword(randomUsername)));
    payload.setEmail(username + "@qstack.com");
    payload.setDepartmentName(departmentName);

    RequestBody reqBody = apiClient.serialize(payload, "application/json");
    Type localVarReturnType = new TypeToken<CreateUser>() { }.getType();
    ApiResponse<CreateUser> responseFromApiClient = apiClient.execute(buildApiCall("POST", url, reqBody), localVarReturnType);
    return responseFromApiClient.getData();
}

public Call buildApiCall(String method, String url, RequestBody reqBody) {
    String signature = null;
    try {
        signature = generateSignature(url);
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return apiCall(method, url, signature, reqBody);
}

private Call apiCall(String method, String url, String signature, RequestBody reqBody) {
    String baseUri = "http://localhost:8002";
    String finalUrl = baseUri + url + "&signature=" + signature;
    final Request.Builder reqBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(finalUrl);
    reqBuilder.header("Accept", "*/*");
    reqBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return httpClient.newCall(reqBuilder.method(method, reqBody).build());
}
```

unit test code

```
 @Test
public void testQuery() {
    String jsonResponse = "{\n" +
            "    \"address_one\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"address_three\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"address_two\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"country_code\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"cs_domain_id\": null,\n" +
            "    \"date_joined\": \"2019-10-02T19:12:55.722764\",\n" +
            "    \"disable_personal_account\": false,\n" +
            "    \"email\": \"username123@qstack.com\",\n" +
            "    \"first_name\": \"username123\",\n" +
            "    \"id\": 73,\n" +
            "    \"is_reseller\": false,\n" +
            "    \"is_superuser\": false,\n" +
            "    \"is_verified\": true,\n" +
            "    \"last_login\": null,\n" +
            "    \"last_name\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"paywall\": true,\n" +
            "    \"postal_code\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"projects\": [],\n" +
            "    \"reference_number\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"reseller_id\": 1,\n" +
            "    \"reseller_name\": \"ROOT\",\n" +
            "    \"reseller_rights\": [],\n" +
            "    \"resource_uri\": \"/api/v1/account/73/\",\n" +
            "    \"saml\": false,\n" +
            "    \"state\": 0,\n" +
            "    \"status\": \"enabled\",\n" +
            "    \"surname\": \"\",\n" +
            "    \"username\": \"username123\",\n" +
            "    \"uuid\": \"9f79e45f-9cc8-40e8-b5c6-bd406893bdd6\"\n" +
            "}";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    CreateUser response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CreateUser.class);
    ApiResponse<CreateUser> responseFromApiClient = new ApiResponse<>(200, null, response);

    OkHttpClient httpClientMock = mock(OkHttpClient.class);
    ApiClient apiClientMock = mock(ApiClient.class);

    when(apiClientMock.serialize(payload, "application/json")).thenReturn(any());
    GqConsoleApiClient g = new GqConsoleApiClient(httpClientMock, apiClientMock);
    Mockito.<ApiResponse<? extends CreateUser>>when(apiClientMock.execute(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseFromApiClient);
    g.createUser("jon", "jon", "jon", "ROOT");

    Assertions.assertEquals("jon", responseFromApiClient.getData().getUsername());
}
```

when looking at coverage output from IntelliJ, I manage to reach the second last line

> ApiResponse responseFromApiClient = apiClient.execute(buildApiCall("POST", url, reqBody), localVarReturnType);

but the test throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method POST must have a request body.

at com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder.method(Request.java:259)
at com.greenqloud.netappstats.collector.metrics.gqconsole.api.GqConsoleApiClient.apiCall(GqConsoleApiClient.java:136)
at com.greenqloud.netappstats.collector.metrics.gqconsole.api.GqConsoleApiClient.buildApiCall(GqConsoleApiClient.java:126)
at com.greenqloud.netappstats.collector.metrics.gqconsole.api.GqConsoleApiClient.createUser(GqConsoleApiClient.java:82)
at com.greenqloud.netappstats.collector.metrics.gqconsole.api.MockitoTest.testQuery(MockitoTest.java:87)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

*Edited new error* after adding new mock call, see `test func.`

```
at io.swagger.cv.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:840)
at com.greenqloud.netappstats.collector.metrics.gqconsole.api.MockitoTest.testQuery(MockitoTest.java:106)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
```

This error points to this function

```
public <T> ApiResponse<T> execute(Call call, Type returnType) throws ApiException {
    try {
        Response response = call.execute();
        T data = handleResponse(response, returnType);
        return new ApiResponse<T>(response.code(), response.headers().toMultimap(), data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ApiException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's going on inside `buildApiCall` method?

Comment: @Sneh added the `buildApiCall` to the question as requested

Comment: The exception tells you what is going on. The Request.Builder required body when doing a POST

Comment: But I'm mocking this function, should then not all parameters input issue been taking care of?

Answer (score 1):

You are not mocking this call

```
apiClient.serialize(payload, "application/json");
```

And as such is probably returning `null`.

Don't forget that apiClient is a mock

```
ApiClient apiClientMock = mock(ApiClient.class);
```

And you are only mocking the `execute` method.

```
Mockito.<ApiResponse<? extends CreateUser>>when(apiClientMock.execute(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseFromApiClient);
```

Fix this by mocking also the `serialize` method.

Comment: is it needed to mock `apiClient.serialize(payload, "application/json");` it has all the necessitated parameters to execute properly?

Comment: Try by yourself to see the result of the call. apiClient is a mock, so there is no real call to the serialize method. So what will that call return?

Comment: tried to mock the `apiClient.serialize`like this `when(apiClientMock.serialize(payload, "application/json")).thenReturn(any());` but threw a different error: see edited original question.

Comment: You must follow the sequence of your code to see where mocking is being used in real code. You are returning any(), so what happens when reqBody is used in buildApiCall? Also are you mocking the httpClient? Another point is that you are now facing a newwproblem and should not edit your original question with another new question..

Comment: I'we been fighting with this for quite some time, and honestly don't think it's worth the hassle! I don't seem to be able to return something from the `apiClient.serialize` func. it returns `RequestBody` and that I can not create manually. Also I seem to need some interaction with `buildApiCall()` and that being class function, I probably should not be mocking that before hand?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the return from serialize (.thenReturn(any())) on this line httpClient.newCall(reqBuilder.method(method, reqBody).build());. Inside reqBuilder is calling methods on reqBody. But reqBody is a mock. So you have to check every method that is being called on reqBody, and return some useful value so reqBuilder can do its thing. If you mock buildApiCall then you are changing the behaviour of the code that you want to test (ie not testing it at all). I suggest you to see a good Mockito tutorial to see all the work that must be done so mocking can work.